# Quarkus native image Chinese encoding problem

Tags: quarkus

I tried all the following methods with no luck.

- quarkus.native.file-encoding=UTF-8
- quarkus.native.add-all-charsets=true
- quarkus.native.additional-build-args=-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,
  -H:-CheckToolchain

Comment: Which is your problem? provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I do not know Chinese but I know Turkish and when I tried I see all characters as they should be, you can see the screenshots at https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/quarkus-examples/issues/1, and here is example code https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/quarkus-examples/blob/master/chinese-lang/src/main/java/com/mascix/GreetingResource.java you can see how I build it https://ozkanpakdil.github.io/quarkus,graalvm/2021/11/03/quarkus-build-native-windows.html